# Can't build simple Xerces program using Netbeans 7.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04/minw/C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-7, xerces

Using Ubuntu 12.04; NetBeans for C++ 7.3.1; minwg; C++11:

Installed ***libxerces-c3.1 --with-recommends***  - from [The Apache Xerces™ Project - xerces.apache.org](http://xerces.apache.org/index.html)

Tried building the simplest code sample provided in the programming guide:

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
// Other include files, declarations, and non-Xerces-C++ initializations.

using namespace xercesc;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  }  catch (const XMLException& toCatch)
  {
    // Do your failure processing here
    return 1;
  }

  // Do your actual work with Xerces-C++ here.

  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

  // Other terminations and cleanup.
  return 0;
}
```

**Getting back these errors when building;**

/home/XYZ/NetBeansProjects/XMLTests/main.cpp:12: **undefined reference to xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale'**

/home/XYZ/NetBeansProjects/XMLTests/main.cpp:12: **undefined reference to xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_1::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)**'

home/XYZ/NetBeansProjects/XMLTests/main.cpp:21: **undefined reference to xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()'**

---

**What am I missing? Do I need to add include paths to my compiler or linker settings? What's wrong? *I am a complete newbee with these libraries.***

Comment: You need to link xerces library

Comment: It is under project properties.